# Detectar la ultima celda que tiene valor con VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy haciendo una macro en excel

En la `hoja1` del libro de excel tengo el formulario con el que capturo la información, y en la `hoja2` se debe guardar esa información leída

Hoja1 (Formulario de captura):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hoja2 (Información capturada):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos si los lee bien pero el problema viene al pasarlos a la `hoja2`, no inserta la nueva captura en la siguiente fila, si no que lo que hace es que la nueva captura la reemplaza en la fila 5.

En el visual basic de excel agregue un modulo y dentro de el codifique mis macros

Macro `Grabar_Datos()`:

```
Sub Grabar_Datos()
    Sheets("Hoja1").Select
    Dim producto As String
    producto = Range("G7").Value
    Dim precio As String
    precio = Range("G9").Value
    Dim cantidad As String
    cantidad = Range("G11").Value
    Dim total As String
    total = Range("G13").Value
    Dim fecha As String
    fecha = Range("G15").Value

    Sheets("Hoja2").Select
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Dim fila As Integer
    fila = ActiveCell.Row
    fila = fila + 1

    Cells(fila, 2).Select
    ActiveCell = producto
    Cells(fila, 3).Select
    ActiveCell = precio
    Cells(fila, 4).Select
    ActiveCell = cantidad
    Cells(fila, 5).Select
    ActiveCell = total
    Cells(fila, 6).Select
    ActiveCell = fecha
End Sub
```

Macro `Limpiar_Datos()`:

```
Sheets("Hoja1").Select
Range("G7:G13").ClearContents
```

Se supone o tengo entendido que esta linea `Selection.End(xlDown).Select` selecciona o activa la ultima celda que tiene un valor pero en mi caso no lo esta haciendo así, lo que hace es que siempre selecciona o marca como activa la celda **B4**

Por que siempre me selecciona esa celda **B4**, como puedo resolver esto??

Revisando un ejemplo que tengo, veo que tengo que agregar texto o un valor antes de la fila del encabezado en mi caso **B3** y tengo que posicionar en esa celda **B3**

```
Sheets("Hoja2").Select
Range("B3").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Dim fila As Integer
fila = ActiveCell.Row
fila = fila + 1
```

De esta manera si funciona correctamente pero habrá alguna manera de solucionar esto??

Que no me vea obligado a posicionar y agregar texto en la celda anterior de la fila del encabezado que en mi caso es **B3**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque yo no hubiera utilizado variables para todo esto ya que sólo lo haces una vez, aquí tienes como quedaría el código corrigiendo varios detalles:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Grabar_Datos()

    'ThisWorkbook se refiere al libro que contiene el código
    'Los bloques With te permiten hacer referencia al objeto que deseas sin escribirlo
    'Vamos a hacer esto para no utilizar los .Select, ya que son malas prácticas y pueden dar
    'lugar a errores.
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1")
        Dim producto As String
        'si pones el . delante de Range, haces referencia al objeto Hoja1 dentro del objeto ThisWorkbook
        producto = .Range("G7")
        Dim precio As String
        precio = .Range("G9")
        Dim cantidad As String
        cantidad = .Range("G11").Value
        Dim total As String
        total = .Range("G13").Value
        Dim fecha As String
        fecha = .Range("G15").Value
    End With
    'Fin del bloque with

    'Ahora otro bloque with para los datos en la hoja2
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja2")
        'La mejor forma de calcular la última fila con datos, es siempre desde abajo
        'Utilizando Cells, puedes darle el número de fila y columna, si utilizas el
        '.Rows.count, te da el número de filas totales que tiene esa hoja
        Dim fila As Long 'jamás declares una variable como integer, es un long truncado
        fila = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        'No es necesario seleccionar una celda para darle un valor, puedes hacerlo así
        .Cells(fila, 2) = producto
        .Cells(fila, 3) = precio
        .Cells(fila, 4) = cantidad
        .Cells(fila, 5) = total
        .Cells(fila, 6) = fecha
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Una observación. Por lo que veo en el código de OP, los datos los coge de `Hoja1`, pero los pega en `Hoja2`. Lo digo porque tu código lo hace todo en `Hoja1`, ¿no?

Comment: Cierto es! ahora edito, gracias @ElierSánchezE-Infantes

Answer (score 0):

Para saber lo que hace realmente la sentencia `Selection.End(xlDown).Select` sitúate en la hoja de Excel, activa la celda B1, presionas la tecla Fin y la flecha hacia abajo, y te darás cuenta del error.

Si en vez de activar la B1, activas la B4 no tendrás problemas.

```
Sheets("Hoja2").Select
Range("B1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Dim fila As Integer
fila = ActiveCell.Row
fila = fila + 1
```

También lo puedes hacer de otra manera, posicionando la macro en una celda lejana, me imagino que imposible de alcanzar, hacia abajo y decirle que encuentre la primera con datos hacia arriba.

Con 
`fila = Range("B65000").End(xlup).Row` obtienes la fila con el último dato.

Así que sería así:

```
Dim fila As Integer
fila = Range("B65000").End(xlup).Row
fila = fila + 1
```

Comment: Selection.End(xlDown).Select ya revise eso y no encuentro ningún error lo único que veo es que siempre selecciona la celda B4

Comment: @Jorge Alonso, edité la respuesta por si te aclara algo más